# Observer Pattern in PHP - Correct Practice for Different Events

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I would like to know if my implementation of the Observer pattern for different events, such as '`userLoggedOut`', '`userRegistered`', '`userLoggedIn`' are correct, below is my simplified code:

**index.php**

```
$login = new \Observer\Observable\Login;
$userData = $login->getData();

$login->attach( new \Observer\Observer\Email );

$login->notify( 'userLoggedIn' );
$login->notify( 'userLoggedOut', $userData );
$login->notify( 'userRegistered' );
```

**Login.php**

```
namespace Observer\Observable;
use Observer\Interfaces;

class Login implements Interfaces\Observable {

    private $observers = array();

    function attach( Interfaces\Observer $object ) {

        $this->observers[] = $object;

    }

    function getObservers() {

        return $this->observers;

    }

    function notify( $action, $data = null ) {

        foreach( $this->observers as $observer ) :

            if( method_exists( $observer, $action ) ) $observer->$action( $data );

        endforeach;

    }

}
```

**Email.php**

```
namespace Observer\Observer;
use Observer\Interfaces;

class Email implements Interfaces\Observer {

    function userLoggedIn( $data = null ) {

        echo "email user logged in";

    }

    function userLoggedOut( $data = null ) {

        echo "email user logged out";

    }

    function userRegistered( $data = null ) {

        echo "email user registered";

    }

}
```

My question is are there better ways of implementing the Observer pattern when dealing with multiple actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're implementation is wrong, but it just doesn't sit right with me. Your Observable has to know the events handler functions and implement them (without an interface of some kind to guarantee they are there. To continue the way you're going I'd make sure anything that would be attached to `Login` should implement an interface that guarantees those action functions will be there. From there, Login doesn't have to learn anything about the observer, it just calls the functions.

Another approach I would take would be to specific the handler for event names, like so:

```
class Observable {
    protected static $event_names = array();
    protected $observers = array();

    function __construct() {
        foreach (static::$event_names as $event_name) {
            $this->observers[$event_name] = array();
        }
    }

    function register($event, $object, $handler) {
        if (array_key_exists($event, $this->observers)) {
            $this->observers[$event][] = array($object, $handler);
        } else {
            echo "Invalid event \"$event\"!";
        }
    }

    function trigger($event, $data = null) {
        foreach ($this->observers[$event] as $observer) {
            $observer[0]->$observer[1]($data);
        }
    }
}

class Login extends Observable {
    protected static $event_names = array("userLoggedIn", "userLoggedOut", "userRegistered");
}
```

And then you're observers would register for events like so:

```
class SomeListener {
    function __construct() {
        $login_instance->register("userLoggedIn", $this, "myLoggedInHandler");
    }

    function myLoggedInHandler($data = null) {
        echo "User Logged In.";
    }
}
```

That's just an opinion though, it's a different approach but then it only requires the knowledge of what events fire (which your method could be argued to do as well, but the Observable should simply just call the handler methods IMO).

Comment: Hi @izuriel, thanks for your suggestions... I'm going to digest this and let you know if I have any further questions... I know what you mean about my implementation not feeling right, it didn't feel right to me either which is why I posted the question.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone Don't get me wrong, there isn't anything inherently wrong with it - that wasn't what I was implying. This is more of an opinion than a a direct answer.

Comment: Hey @izuriel, I know... I guess its hard to know with these things as I guess everyone has their own slight differences and implementations. Its always hard when your new to such things such as design patterns as there are so many people that say different things. I'm just plodding along improving bit by bit and gaining knowledge from people like you.